# Set same height as other divs, without javascript, and inside flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve this:

[image: What I want to do]

I set a `max-width` to my paragraph, and I want the two images to have the same height as the paragraph. But the problem is I have a complex flexbox design, as shown below.

Red and green boxes are divs with `display: flex` property, and blue boxes are content. I made this schema to make the whole thing responsive for small landscape screens (sorry my 2nd drawing looks like it's on mobile).

Large screens:

[image: Large screens]

Small screens:

[image: Small screens]

So here is what I have right now, with `height: 100%` on the images:

[image: What I have now]

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS? I tried javascript but there are conflicts between flexbox and JS, which lead to this: [video of how my JS/CSS conflict looks like](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaregore/comments/fpfvqf/im_the_one_who_made_this_but_this_conflict/)

Thanks!

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#row1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#row1 #row1_col1 {
  display: inline-flex;
}
#row1 #row1_col1 #photo {
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
#row1 #row1_col1 p {
  background-color: coral;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit content;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 31em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#row1 #map {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">

  <div id="row1_col1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" id="photo" class="about_imgs">

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. <br> <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Uot enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. <br> <br>
      xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proiden.
    </p>

  </div>

  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1053x526" id="map" class="about_imgs">

</div>
```

Comment: Which element should define the overall height ? is it the p and then the images should stay within that height or what exactly ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes, the p has to define the overall height

Comment: I don't think you can do that, the biggest element will define the overall height which is in this case the right image.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, first of all, you should make both of used `align-items` property have `flex-start` attribute just like this: `align-items: flex-start;` as I did in the below snippet to make sure all your items begin from the same place (keep in mind this is optional and for making sure all your items will begin from the same certain point in the UI, and if you don't want to do this you can skip this), the second thing you must consider is the `p` tag does the default margin from top and bottom so to override it with `margin: 0;` in the `p` tag itself. The last and important thing at all you should define a fixed height for your `p` tag also, and make sure your photos wouldn't pass a certain point with the `max-height` property, so you have to add this property to both of your images. You can see the results below:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#row1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#row1 #row1_col1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#row1 #row1_col1 #photo {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

#row1 #row1_col1 p {
  background-color: coral;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit content;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 31em;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}

#row1 #map {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div id="row1_col1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" id="photo" class="about_imgs">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. <br> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Uot enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. <br> <br> xcepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proiden.
    </p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1053x526" id="map" class="about_imgs">
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I just used `200px` for the fixed height for more illustration it could be whatever you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately that is not exactly what I want to do. In your snippet, you fixed the height of the paragraph, but there is some space at its end. What I want to do is set the height of the other elements depending on the height of the paragraph, which has to be the exact height of its content

Comment: @clementlize  So there is no possible way to do it with CSS alone and it should contain some logic in it and we should use JS as well if you willing to work with JS into this example I will put an update for you shortly. Please just let me know about it.

Comment: @SMAKKS I managed to get it work with JS for large screens, but I have some problems with low resolutions due to a conflict between JS and flexbox as you can see in the video link I put in the question. Anyway, I think I will rethink the way I want it to look and set a fixed height as you mentioned in the answer, it will be ok with media queries and I won't have any conflicts. Thanks again!